# Major changes in sorting method of glibc on Ubuntu 18.04 after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, postgresql, glibc

I had an Ubuntu 18.04.0 with Postgres 9.6.

Before Ubuntu upgrade following command result was:

```
vodka@ubuntu140:~$  ( echo "1-1"; echo "11" ) | LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort
1-1
11
```

But after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to latest release via `apt upgrade` (18.04.5) result of the command above totally changed:

```
vodka@ubuntu140:~$ ( echo "1-1"; echo "11" ) | LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort
11
1-1
```

Due to this our production Postgres database started work very slowly and we had a long downtime for REINDEX. Sorting method is very important for Postgres database:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes

Please, read "Testing collation" part.

Is it normal behavior for Ubuntu? Why glibc totally changed within LTS release without 'major upgrade'? I did not expect this...

Answer (score 1):

> Why glibc totally changed within LTS release without 'major upgrade'?

It didn't.

18.04.5 is based on glibc-2.27, which still has the "old" [Unicode CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/).

The updated CLDR comes with glibc-2.28.

The result that you get with 18.04.5 seems legit, whereas the result you mention with 18.04.0 is weird, as if an older release had a newer glibc library, and 18.04.0 => 18.04.5 did a downgrade.

In other words, the result you mention as old is actually new (in the future from the point of view of 18.04) and the result you mention as new is old.